# How do I Join the Array using jquery?

Tags: javascript

it gives me error like a.join is not a function

```
var a = ["16-25", "26-35", '36-50'];
var myVar2 = a.join(', ');
console.log(myVar2);
```

Comment: It's working https://jsfiddle.net/LuyLbgb6/

Comment: What browser are you using when you get this error?

Comment: There is no jQuery here, and your code works fine when I paste it into the JavaScript console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like

```
 job.kids_age_range = ["1-5","6-10"]
```

has not been generated like shown but is possibly an "array-like" object (like the `arguments` object of a function) without actually *being* an array and having all its methods. You could try and apply the jquery method

```
var kids_age=$.makeArray(job.kids_age_range);
```

to actually *make* it an array which will then have the `join()` method available.

**Addition:**

You can achieve the same thing *without jquery* by doing

```
kids_age=Array.prototype.slice.call(job.kids_age_range,0);
```